# Why would an experimental shallow wave be faster than a theoretical shallow wave?

Tags: waves, water

I did an experiment where I looked at the relationship between water depth and wave speed for shallow water waves. My data shows that the waves I created were faster than the theoretical values. Is there a theory/concept that could explain why this happened?

See video of trial here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PBXgW9d8J4NrCa86lxeekI1xPIe5MWsx/view?usp=sharing

In the experiment I lifted the side of a fish tank filled with water and placed it back. I measured the time it would take for the wave to move from end of the tank to the other. I only took data for first few wavelengths, where there was little wave interference.

Comment: What was your water depth when undisturbed?

Comment: Water depth was the independent variable so I changed it up during the experiment. In this specific trial is was around 1.5cm

Comment: What is the theoretical value you compared with?

Comment: Basically I graphed square root of depth vs the wave speed, according to the shallow water equation (https://www.encyclopedia.com/earth-and-environment/ecology-and-environmentalism/environmental-studies/celerity#:~:text=celerity%20The%20velocity%20with%20which%20a%20wave%20advances.&text=The%20speed%20of%20shallow%2Dwater,depth%20of%20water%20in%20metres.) The slope of the graph should be the square root of the acceleration of gravity, about 3.13m/s^2. My value was around 3.3m/s^2.

Comment: Link dead: _Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist._